# is it possibe to change the processor

Tags: laptop, cpu

Is it possible to change the i3 processor into i5 ?
My laptop is HP DV6

Comment: not specific enough...we need a specific model number or preferably a motherboard model to tell you that

Answer (score 1):

Laptops usually have the CPU soldered to the motherboard, so I doubt it.

Comment: not necessarily in this case, the hp dv6000 series manual here: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01035677.pdf states removal is possible

Comment: @aking1012: Oh, okay.  I am not as familiar with large laptops as with mid-size, ultraportables and netbooks.  I do know that particular model though - they are extremely prone to hinge failure.  It's a design fault.

Comment: it's cool, i have a dv7(another of the large-ish ones 17" screen)